# What is the range of the interaction in nuclear physics?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

What is the *range of the interaction* R, in nuclear physics?

$R=c\Delta t$

where $t$ is the time interval in which some virtual particle is exchanged.

Or, for beta decay, the range of the intercation is given by:

$R=\frac{\hbar}{m_Wc}$

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/589807/how-to-calculate-or-do-we-observe-range-of-exchange-particles-in-qft).

Answer (score 4):

You just wrote down the range of interaction:

$$ R = \frac{\hbar}{mc} =  \frac{\hbar c}{mc^2}$$

Note that all nuclear physicists know:

$$\hbar c = 197\, {\rm Mev\cdot fm} $$

and have memorized all the masses of the light mesons, so:

$$ R = \frac{197\, {\rm Mev\cdot fm}}{m_{\pi}c^2} = \frac{197\, {\rm Mev\cdot fm}}{140{\,\rm MeV}} \approx 1.4\,{\rm fm}$$

which is comparable to the proton size.

Regarding propagation times of virtual particles...that's not really a fruitful line of thinking.